# Cordova cant push lng and lat to mysql server

Tags: php, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am trying to use the phonegap geolocation api to store the longitude and latitude of an android device on my mysql server.  Here is the code that is perfectly getting the longitude and latitude but i dont seem to be able to pass them to the php script that should post them to my server.

Could anyone identify the problem with my ajax?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //find location info//
        function geolocation(){
            var options = enableHighAccuracy = true;
          watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);

        //this functions runs if geolocation is returned//
            function onSuccess(position) {
                var lat = position.coords.latitude;
                var lng = position.coords.longitude;
                //save to local storage
                localStorage.setItem("latitude", lat);
                localStorage.setItem("longitude", lng);
                //tell user their lng and lat
                //alert("lat: " + lat + "long: " + lng);
                //var userID = $(this).attr('id');
                            var getlat = window.localStorage.getItem("latitude");
                            var getlng = window.localStorage.getItem("longitude");
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                dataType: 'text',
                                url: 'http://myserver.com/upload.php',
                                data: { latitude : getlat, longitude : getlng },
                                success: function(data)
                                {
                                    //alert("Location Data Sent!");
                                },
                                complete:function remove(){
                                    localStorage.removeItem("latitude");
                                    localStorage.removeItem("longitude");
                                },
                                error: function(){
                                    alert('Code 303A');
                                }
                            });
            }
            //if cant get location give error//
            function onError(error) {
                alert("message: " + error.message);
                localStorage.setItem("message", error.message);
             }
            }
        geolocation();
    </script>
```

Comment: You have to whitelisten external sources.

Comment: @Joerg whitelist is already added to my project

Comment: What callback function gets fired?  success or error?

Comment: @SteveKennedy it fails to send parse the coordinates to the php script. The values passed are blank

Comment: Try changine data: { latitude : getlat, longitude : getlng } to data: { latitude : lat, longitude : lng } and pass in the localized variables, rather then the ones you get from the localStorage?